# Unit Test Cases for Django Admin.py operations

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

This is my first Django Project. In my admin.py file I have defined fields and search_fields. I am wondering how I can write test cases to validate these.

Code snippet:

```
class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['name']
    search_fields = ['name']
```

Is it required to have unit test cases for these things?

Answer (score 1):

I often mess up names in search_fields, list_display, etc. I put together the following test case as my first attempt to validate. I ran across your question when I was searching Stack Overflow for better or more complete solutions and figured I might as well drop my code here since your question didn't have any answers.

```
model_classnames = ['MyModelX', 'MyModelY', 'MyModelZ']

admin_fieldname_lists = ['list_display', 'search_fields']

class TestAdminConfig(TestCase):

    def test_admin_fieldname_lists(self):
        for model_classname in model_classnames:
            model_class = locate("tasks.models.%s" % model_classname)
            admin_class = locate("tasks.admin.%sAdmin" % model_classname)
            #print("classes: %s, %s" % (model_class.__name__, admin_class.__name__))
            for list_name in admin_fieldname_lists:
                #print("    list: %s" % list_name)
                for fieldname in getattr(admin_class, list_name):
                    fieldname = fieldname.replace("^", "")
                    #print("       field: %s" % fieldname)
                    if fieldname in dir(model_class): continue
                    if fieldname in dir(admin_class): continue
                    model_class.objects.filter(**{fieldname:None})
```

In a nutshell, this cycles through all the model / fieldname combos and decides that any given "fieldname" is OK if it can be found on the Model class, the corresponding ModelAdmin class, or is a more complicated string like "foo__auth_user__first_name" that works as a filter. The code removes "^" characters that sometimes prefix search_fields.

Since your question is old, did you eventually find your own solution? If so, what was it?